# UserNamePasswordValidator in Abstract class

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, wcf-security

I have created a WCF web service. The design is as follows:

I have an Abstract (MustInherit in VB .Net) class which has one method (an instance to my dbml Linq To SQL context) which for this example I will call it DBMLContext.

I create my Contract as needed.

I implement the contract class as required and inherit the Abstract class (DBMLContext) to use the one method to return/update/delete data as required against the methods I have.

This all works fine.

I now would like to add security (username and password to the service) and need to inherit `System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator`. When adding it to my class with all the methods i need, i get the error that only one base class can be inherited (currently inheriting DBMLContext)

Now i could add an inherit statement to the Abstract class (for `System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator`) but I don't know if this would be appropriate or if there is another way to do what I'm doing and most importantly if this is a secure way?

Overall I'm trying to ensure the WCF service uses a username and password for any access.